# JQuery selector onchange event

Tags: jquery

I have a file input as follows :

```
<input type="file" id="file">
```

I wanted to write some action for the onChange event of the file as follows :

```
$("#file").change(function(){});
```

But this did not work. Then I changed the code as follows : and it worked

```
$("input#file").change(function(){});
```

My question is why is it necessary to pass **"input#file"** inside **$()** as in other cases, only id is enough. For example for the click event following is enough :

```
$("#file").click(function(){});
```

Comment: does it work if you change the id ? for example from _id="file"_  to _id="fileControl"_ ? maybe that is reserved to query by type.

Comment: It works unless you have duplicate IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propably you have another element with the `id = "file"`.